# Hide overflow of an image with a greater width than the body

Tags: html, css

I have several images and they all have a really big empty margin. I have to make them bigger than the viewport width in small screens to make them have the size the client wants but this produces an empty overflow. I can't seem to hide the overflow of the image. Here is the code of the image and it's container:

HTML:

```
<div class="product">
    <img alt="floor" id="img-product">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.product {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#img-product{
    width: 150vw;
    position: absolute;
    content: url("image.png");
}
```

I have also used in #img-product: width:500px;

Comment: Could you please add here an image example and the target result (image with white margins centered on the screen, so these margins are out of the screen, is that correct?)

Comment: I'll upload an image in a few minutes but you are right. Margins on left and right and the image is centered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the img is positioned absolutely with regards to the entire HTML document, so the parent .product has no power over it.

Solution: position the .product, so that the positioning of the img is relative to the .product.

```css
.product {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width:100%;        /* for demonstration purposes */
    height:100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative; /* new */
}

#img-product{
    width: 150vw;
    position: absolute;
    content: url("image.png"); /* note: this doesn't do anything. */
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
    <img alt="floor" id="img-product" src="https://placehold.it/640x100">
</div>
```

Please note that I had to add a src attribute to the img for demonstration purposes, since the `content` property doesn't do anything here, and a height to the .product, otherwise it would collapse.